# scrapy how to set JOBDIR from the code not cmd

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

When i run my spider from terminal like this:

```
scrapy crawl GeneralSpider --set JOBDIR=will
```

everything works find and i can see the JOBDIR folder

however, when i try to set it programatically, like this:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
        myS = get_project_settings()
        myS.set(myS, 'JOBDIR', "folder")
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
CRITICAL:twisted:Unhandled error in Deferred:
2016-02-15 17:49:35 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 70, in crawl
    self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in _create_spider
    return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/bla bla bla spider.py", line 47, in __init__
    myS.set(myS, 'JOBDIR', "myfolder")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 94, in set
    priority = SETTINGS_PRIORITIES[priority]
exceptions.KeyError: 'myfolder'
CRITICAL:twisted:
2016-02-15 17:49:35 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/85f0596c43781103f30eaff13b567942ff967e00/scrapy/extensions/spiderstate.py) and [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/75cd056223a5a8da87a361aee42a541afcf27553/scrapy/utils/job.py) could help you. Or you could just [search for JOBDIR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=JOBDIR) in the scrapy github project and read how they do it.

Answer (score 3):

The [Settings API set method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.settings.Settings.set) has this signature:

> set(name, value, priority='project')

You're passing a settings object as setting name, and "myfolder" as priority, which is not expected.

Try doing this instead:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
...
        myS = get_project_settings()
        myS.set('JOBDIR', "folder")
```